# RegExp: Match all links except youtube links with videos

Tags: php, regex, youtube, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

[RegExp I have constructed](https://regex101.com/r/KsjAOL/13) so far:

```
(?(DEFINE)
  # URL
  (?<proto> (https?:)?\/\/)
  (?<port> :[0-9]{2,5})
  (?<tld> (?:com|net|info|biz|us|org))
  (?<path> (\/([a-z0-9+%-]\.?)+)*\/?)
  (?<query> \?[a-z+&$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/.-]*)
  (?<hash> \#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+$%_.-]*)
  (?<subdomain> ([a-z0-9\-\.]+)\.)

  # Exceptions
 (?<yt_domain> (www\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/)
 (?<yt_hash> ([\w-]{10,12})+)
 (?<yt_video> \g<proto>?\g<yt_domain>+(watch)?(\/embed\/|\?v=)+\g<yt_hash>+)
)

# Capture
((?!\g<yt_video>+.*)
  (\g<proto>?
  \g<subdomain>
  \g<tld>
  \g<port>?
  \g<path>?
  \g<query>?
  \g<hash>?
))
```

I managed to capture links in any format, but for some reason my negative lookahead (see `\g<yt_video>`) doesn't exclude youtube video links from matches list.

Lines which should be partially or fully matched:

> http:www.google.com/
>   http//www.google.com/
>   http://www.google.com/
>   ://www.google.com/
>   www.google.com/
>   www.google.com:8000
>   www.google.com/?key=value
>   github.io
>   www.google.com/abc/def/ijk#123
>   www.google.com/abc/def/ijk?v=123123123
>   www.google.com/abc/def/watch?v=1231231231
>   https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCgeu2xe0XRscaKyvBt3WgmQ
>   http://www.google.com/?key=value
>   http://www.youtube.com/

However, it should skip (do not match lines) which contain youtube video ID):

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5Gj78s6H7w&feature=youtu.be
>   https://www.youtube.com/embed/y19EaW2X7ac
>   music.youtube.com/embed/y19EaW2X7ac
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5Gj78s6H7w&feature=youtu.be
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=B5Gj78s6H7w
>   https://www.youtu.be/B5Gj78s6H7w&feature=youtu.be
>   https://www.youtu.be/B5Gj78s6H7w

Thank you in advance for the help or any hint why negative lookahead does not negate lines.

Comment: Maybe you may just fail any string having `youtube.com` or `youtu.be`? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KsjAOL/14).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this won't work, I don't want to fail `youtube.com` links, because they are subject to later conversion into an embed entities.

Comment: Which regex is actual, the one in the regex101 link or in the question?

Comment: In question is actual, but they are almost the same, I was just playing with regex101. Neither of them works :)

Comment: Why all the unnamed captures in the functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some messing around with this, the way you diagnose the *NOT* youtube
function is to comment out the rest of it and see what it matches.

What you have to understand about lookahead assertions is all they tell the
engine is that in the current position there can't be *the thing* ahead of it.
All it does is advance the position by 1 and try it again.
Does this until it gets to a position where the assertion passes.

Since you don't have any anchors, it matches parts of the line with something else.

So, you have to *get past* this stretch of text to avoid parts of it.

There are a couple of ways around this but by far the easiest is to  match it then
`(*SKIP) (*FAIL)` past it.
The engine doesn't actually match it, but it puts the current position just past it
and tries again.

I've gotten rid of (or converted to clusters) unnecessary capture groups.
Added the skip/fail, turned your TLD's into a ternary trie and formatted for
reading purposes.

Get [RegexFormat 8](http://www.regexformat.com) which does this for you and has
a built in engine for regex testing.

Note also that this `(?: [\w-]{10,12} )+` has a granularity of 10-12 char's at a time. Where as `[\w-]{10,}` will match > 10 chars. It is in the `<yt_hash>` function. And in calling it with this `(?&yt_hash)+`, the quantifier is redundant/useless.

Since it now successfully skips some in the call to `(?&yt_video) .*`
you'll have to investigate that function's parts, to see why it doesn't
match, and therefore *SKIP* others.

Here it is compressed

https://regex101.com/r/pOq3Hc/1

```
/(?i)(?(DEFINE)(?<proto>(?:https?:)?\/\/)(?<port>:[0-9]{2,5})(?<tld>(?:a(?:[cd]|e(?:ro)?|[fgil-oqr]|s(?:ia)?|[tuwxz])|b(?:[abd-h]|iz?|[jl-oq-tvwyz])|c(?:at?|[cdf-ik-n]|o(?:m|op)?|[ru-z])|d[ejkmoz]|e[ceghr-u]|f[i-kmor]|g[abd-il-np-uwy]|h[kmnrtu]|i(?:[delm]|n(?:fo|t)?|[oq-t])|j(?:[em]|o(?:bs)?|p)|k[eg-imnprwyz]|l[a-cikr-vy]|m(?:[ac-hk]|lc?|[mn]|o(?:bi)?|[p-t]|u(?:seum)?|[v-z])|n(?:a(?:me)?|c|et?|[fgilopruz])|o(?:m|rg)|p(?:[ae-hk-n]|ost|ro?|[stwy])|qa|r[eosuw]|s(?:[a-eg-or]|t(?:udio)?|[uvx-z])|t(?:[cd]|el|[f-hj-p]|r(?:avel)?|[tvwz])|u[agkmsyz]|v[aceginu]|w[fs]|y[et]|z[amw]))(?<path>(\/(?:[a-z0-9+%-]\.?)+)*\/?)(?<query>\?[a-z+&$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/.-]*)(?<hash>\#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+$%_.-]*)(?<subdomain>[a-z0-9\-\.]+\.)(?<yt_domain>(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/)(?<yt_hash>(?:[\w-]{10,12})+)(?<yt_video>(?&proto)?(?&yt_domain)+(?:watch)?(?:\/embed\/|\?v=)+(?&yt_hash)+))((?&yt_video).*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?&proto)?(?&subdomain)(?&tld)(?&port)?(?&path)?(?&query)?(?&hash)?)/
```

And expanded

```
 (?i)
 (?(DEFINE)
      # URL
      (?<proto>                                          # (1 start)
           (?: https?: )?
           //
      )                                                  # (1 end)
      (?<port> : [0-9]{2,5} )                            # (2)
      (?<tld>                                            # (3 start)
           (?:
                a
                (?:
                     [cd] 
                  |  e
                     (?: ro )?
                  |  [fgil-oqr] 
                  |  s
                     (?: ia )?
                  |  [tuwxz] 
                )
             |  b
                (?: [abd-h] | iz? | [jl-oq-tvwyz] )
             |  c
                (?:
                     at?
                  |  [cdf-ik-n] 
                  |  o
                     (?: m | op )?
                  |  [ru-z] 
                )
             |  d [ejkmoz] 
             |  e [ceghr-u] 
             |  f [i-kmor] 
             |  g [abd-il-np-uwy] 
             |  h [kmnrtu] 
             |  i
                (?:
                     [delm] 
                  |  n
                     (?: fo | t )?
                  |  [oq-t] 
                )
             |  j
                (?:
                     [em] 
                  |  o
                     (?: bs )?
                  |  p
                )
             |  k [eg-imnprwyz] 
             |  l [a-cikr-vy] 
             |  m
                (?:
                     [ac-hk] 
                  |  lc?
                  |  [mn] 
                  |  o
                     (?: bi )?
                  |  [p-t] 
                  |  u
                     (?: seum )?
                  |  [v-z] 
                )
             |  n
                (?:
                     a
                     (?: me )?
                  |  c
                  |  et?
                  |  [fgilopruz] 
                )
             |  o
                (?: m | rg )
             |  p
                (?: [ae-hk-n] | ost | ro? | [stwy] )
             |  qa
             |  r [eosuw] 
             |  s
                (?:
                     [a-eg-or] 
                  |  t
                     (?: udio )?
                  |  [uvx-z] 
                )
             |  t
                (?:
                     [cd] 
                  |  el
                  |  [f-hj-p] 
                  |  r
                     (?: avel )?
                  |  [tvwz] 
                )
             |  u [agkmsyz] 
             |  v [aceginu] 
             |  w [fs] 
             |  y [et] 
             |  z [amw] 
           )

      )                                                  # (3 end)
      (?<path>                                           # (4 start)
           (                                                  # (5 start)
                /
                (?: [a-z0-9+%-] \.? )+
           )*                                                 # (5 end)
           /?
      )                                                  # (4 end)
      (?<query> \? [a-z+&$_.-] [a-z0-9;:@&%=+/.-]* )     # (6)
      (?<hash> \# [a-z_.-] [a-z0-9+$%_.-]* )             # (7)
      (?<subdomain>                                      # (8 start)
           [a-z0-9\-\.]+ 
           \.
      )                                                  # (8 end)

      # Exceptions
      (?<yt_domain>                                      # (9 start)
           (?: www\. )?
           (?: youtube\.com | youtu\.be )
           /
      )                                                  # (9 end)
      (?<yt_hash>                                        # (10 start)
           (?: [\w-]{10,12} )+
      )                                                  # (10 end)
      (?<yt_video>                                       # (11 start)
           (?&proto)? (?&yt_domain)+ 
           (?: watch )?
           (?: /embed/ | \?v= )+
           (?&yt_hash)+ 
      )                                                  # (11 end)
 )

 # Capture
 (                                                  # (12 start)
      (?&yt_video) .* 
      (*SKIP) (*FAIL) 
   |  
      (?&proto)? 
      (?&subdomain) 
      (?&tld) 
      (?&port)? 
      (?&path)? 
      (?&query)? 
      (?&hash)? 
 )                                                  # (12 end)
```

Comment: Thank you, really great idea with SKIP/FAIL!